# Bash sed replace until end of line

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following input file:

```
this is text
     identifier {
         item /directory/file_1234 
some more text 
item /directory/file_1234 other line text
     identifier {
         item /directory/98_76file
other line
```

I want to replace the stings `item /directory/*`, that come after the line `identifier {` with `/directory/file_ABC`

I tried

```
cat input | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/    identifier {\n        item \/directory\/.*$/    identifier {\n        newitem \/directory2\/file_ABC/g'
```

but it erases the lines after the first occurrence

```
this is text
    identifier {
        newitem /directory2/file_ABC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace both occurances, you can use this `sed`

```
$ sed '/identifier {/{N;s~\(.*\n[^[:alpha:]]*\).*~\1newitem /directory/file_ABC~}' input_file
this is text
     identifier {
         newitem /directory/file_ABC
some more text
item /directory/file_1234 other line text
     identifier {
         newitem /directory/file_ABC
other line
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes form the final `.*$` of your pattern: in multi-line mode it matches until the end of the pattern space. Try (tested with GNU `sed`):

```bash
$ sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s!((^|\n) +identifier \{\n +)item /directory/[^\n]*!\1newitem /directory2/file_ABC!g' input
this is text
     identifier {
         newitem /directory2/file_ABC
some more text 
item /directory/file_1234 other line text
     identifier {
         newitem /directory2/file_ABC
other line
```

Note: using `cat` to feed `sed` is an anti-pattern. Simply `sed 'script' file`.

Note: using `!` as fields separator of the substitute command instead of `/` avoids escapes and using the `-E` option simplifies a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/identifier \{/{n;s#(/directory/).*#\1file_ABC#;}' file
```

Turn on extended regexps by setting `-E`.

Match on a line containing `identifier {` and print then fetch the next line.

If the line matches `/directory/` replace that by itself and `file_ABC`.